# How to build a component library in Angular by extending an existing one

Tags: angular, primeng, angular-library, angular11

We have been using ng-bootstrap with bootstrap 4 with its base theme to build our web app in Angular 11.  ng-bootstrap has proved to be limited for our requirements and over time we have to add other 3rd party libs to extend its functionality.

Also we now have a design team that has given us a design system with a new theme and custom components. This makes it a good time to switch libraries or build one. We have found that in terms of variety - PrimeNG is the most extensive component library for Angular and would like to leverage it to build our own component library.

Even with PrimeNG there are a few missing components that we would have to build and some PrimeNG components like the editor that we will have to modify to add support for tables etc.

Our initial plan is to create a Angular Library project that imports PrimeNG and exports all the modules that it has. Forking the component library repos was ruled out because we want to keep our changes private with our themes and also we would like to keep up with PrimeNG's fixes/updates.

With that said, we have a couple of questions about using another library to build our own

1. What impact would this have on the bundle size - in case of components that are wrapped?
2. Are there any examples of an Angular component library being built out of another one? PrimeNG itself does extend Quill and FullCalendar but they are single libraries in one sense not libraries with a lot of individual components.

Any other tips or warnings about this approach would also be helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. It not have major effect on bundle sizes if you modularize the components properly. Webpack take care of treeshaking and reducing the bundle sizes.
2. you can find lot many libraries on npmjs.com. just check https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/material of angular material. So many component libraries are built from it.

It get hard to support newer versions as you go but I would not go with this approach since you will have to do lot many hacks to make work.  As you won't have access to any of library internal js but only exported components but it is dependant on Lib implementing.

Answer (score 0):

Wanted to close out with the approach we took after internal discussions and advice from other front-end developers. Of course this is what we thought was best for our requirements with the current set of time and resources we have on hand.

1. We are continuing with the bootstrap css grid system since we are used to it and much of the application uses it. Only change we made was to shift from Bootstrap 4 to 5 since we were forking the CSS for our customization anyway.
2. For components, we are building off of primeng. It is not a layer on top of primeng, we are taking the components that we really need from the library and styling to suit our design.
3. We are building the components as a angular library that can be used across projects. To test individual components as we build them, we are using storybook.

Comment: I am looking to do the same and am curious, was it successful? Any tips / pitfalls to avoid?